# Why are Apple Watch activity rings moving on by themselves?

Tags: hardware, apple-watch, watchos

I am observing my Apple Watch activity rings are moving insanely. I did talk to customer service they were also unable to help me. Did anyone face the issue before?

What happened today?

- I wore the watch to the gym and started the Aaptiv app in my iPhone 7 Plus. In the workout I did use my workout app.
- After the workout was over, I found the watch using aaptiv app by itself, no idea how and why?
  And my activity rings are increasing insanely.

I did unpair and pair the watch. I uninstalled the aaptiv  app from Apple Watch. But still the problem persists.  I don’t know how to factory reset the watch. I did not try this option.

How can I stop the rings from increasing without any movement?

[image: Apple watch activity rings are moving insane]

[image: Activity app in phone]

Answer (score 2):

Could be another app recording a workout automatically. 
Check the Health app or the Workouts tab in the app you screenshotted, to see if you have any apps registering additional workouts in the background.